# Spring Boot Failing to Start Correctly

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

My Spring Boot application is failing at startup, with the log below. What does this mean?

I'm using Hibernate Core v5.0.11.Final.

```html
<pre>

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.4.1.RELEASE)

2016-09-27 02:55:31.899  INFO 5329 --- [           main] c.t.application.TaqnihomeApplication     : Starting TaqnihomeApplication on Songlines-MacBook-Air.local with PID 5329 (/Users/songline/Downloads/assignment-2/target/classes started by songline in /Users/songline/Downloads/assignment-2)
2016-09-27 02:55:31.904  INFO 5329 --- [           main] c.t.application.TaqnihomeApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2016-09-27 02:55:32.092  INFO 5329 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@7722c3c3: startup date [Tue Sep 27 02:55:32 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-09-27 02:55:33.792  INFO 5329 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'dataSource' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Generic; factoryMethodName=dataSource; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Generic.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari; factoryMethodName=dataSource; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]]
2016-09-27 02:55:34.412  INFO 5329 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8ec63a75] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-09-27 02:55:35.085  INFO 5329 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2016-09-27 02:55:35.103  INFO 5329 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2016-09-27 02:55:35.104  INFO 5329 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.5
2016-09-27 02:55:35.280  INFO 5329 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2016-09-27 02:55:35.280  INFO 5329 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3192 ms
2016-09-27 02:55:35.492  INFO 5329 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2016-09-27 02:55:35.497  INFO 5329 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2016-09-27 02:55:35.498  INFO 5329 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2016-09-27 02:55:35.498  INFO 5329 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2016-09-27 02:55:35.498  INFO 5329 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2016-09-27 02:55:35.798  INFO 5329 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2016-09-27 02:55:35.818  INFO 5329 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
 name: default
 ...]
2016-09-27 02:55:35.917  INFO 5329 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.11.Final}
2016-09-27 02:55:35.919  INFO 5329 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2016-09-27 02:55:35.921  INFO 5329 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2016-09-27 02:55:35.990  INFO 5329 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2016-09-27 02:55:36.268  INFO 5329 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Started.
2016-09-27 02:55:36.528  INFO 5329 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
2016-09-27 02:55:37.223  INFO 5329 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
2016-09-27 02:55:37.266  INFO 5329 --- [           main] rmationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl : HHH000262: Table not found: game_library
2016-09-27 02:55:37.363  WARN 5329 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
2016-09-27 02:55:37.364  INFO 5329 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Close initiated...
2016-09-27 02:55:37.370  INFO 5329 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Closed.
2016-09-27 02:55:37.372  INFO 5329 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
2016-09-27 02:55:37.390  INFO 5329 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2016-09-27 02:55:37.398 ERROR 5329 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1583) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1076) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:851) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
 at com.taqnihome.application.TaqnihomeApplication.main(TaqnihomeApplication.java:34) [classes/:na]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
 at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:954) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
 at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:882) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
 at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353) ~[spring-orm-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:373) ~[spring-orm-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:362) ~[spring-orm-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1642) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1579) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
 ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Unable to execute schema management to JDBC target [alter table game_library add column game_id varchar(255) not null]
 at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.TargetDatabaseImpl.accept(TargetDatabaseImpl.java:59) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
 at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.applySqlString(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:431) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
 at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:449) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
 at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.migrateTable(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:253) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
 at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.doMigrationToTargets(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:170) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
 at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.doMigration(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:60) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
 at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:134) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
 at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
 at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:472) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
 at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
 at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
 ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'testingjpa.game_library' doesn't exist
 at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:686) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
 at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:663) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
 at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:653) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
 at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:115) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
 at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2041) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
 at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdateInternal(StatementImpl.java:1608) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
 at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeLargeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:2630) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
 at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1534) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
 at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyStatement.java:120) ~[HikariCP-2.4.7.jar:na]
 at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-2.4.7.jar:na]
 at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.TargetDatabaseImpl.accept(TargetDatabaseImpl.java:56) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
 ... 32 common frames omitted
</pre>
```

Log TLDR;

```
HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
HHH000262: Table not found: game_library
```

GameLibrary class:

```
@Entity 
@Table(name = "game_library")
public class GameLibrary {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "game_id")
    private String gameId;
    @Column(name = "game_name")
    private String gameName;
    @Column(name = "game_genre")
    private String gameGenre;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "game_category", nullable = false)
    private GameCategory gameCategory;
    @Column(name = "game_version")
    private String gameVersion;
    @Column(name = "game_publiher")
    private String gamePublisher;
    @Column(name = "game_studio")
    private String gameStudio;
    @Column(name = "game_release_date")
    private Long gameReleaseDate;

    @Column
    private Double gameRating;

    @Column
    private String gamePlatform;
    @Column
    private Long creationDate;
    @Column
    private String googlePlayUrl;
    @Column
    private Long approvedDate;
    @Column
    private Boolean isApproved;
    @Column
    private String packageName;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "gameLibrary", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<GameProfile> gameProfiles;

    // getters and setters
}
```

new log when update change with create   field value ddl-auto

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.4.1.RELEASE)

2016-09-27 12:47:50.815  INFO 5812 --- [           main] c.t.application.TaqnihomeApplication     : Starting TaqnihomeApplication on Songlines-MacBook-Air.local with PID 5812 (/Users/songline/Downloads/assignment-2/target/classes started by songline in /Users/songline/Downloads/assignment-2)
2016-09-27 12:47:50.818  INFO 5812 --- [           main] c.t.application.TaqnihomeApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2016-09-27 12:47:50.939  INFO 5812 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@7722c3c3: startup date [Tue Sep 27 12:47:50 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-09-27 12:47:52.624  INFO 5812 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'dataSource' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Generic; factoryMethodName=dataSource; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Generic.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari; factoryMethodName=dataSource; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]]
2016-09-27 12:47:53.213  INFO 5812 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8ec63a75] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-09-27 12:47:53.853  INFO 5812 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2016-09-27 12:47:53.874  INFO 5812 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2016-09-27 12:47:53.876  INFO 5812 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.5
2016-09-27 12:47:54.085  INFO 5812 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2016-09-27 12:47:54.085  INFO 5812 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3153 ms
2016-09-27 12:47:54.275  INFO 5812 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2016-09-27 12:47:54.281  INFO 5812 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2016-09-27 12:47:54.281  INFO 5812 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2016-09-27 12:47:54.282  INFO 5812 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2016-09-27 12:47:54.282  INFO 5812 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2016-09-27 12:47:54.529  INFO 5812 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2016-09-27 12:47:54.552  INFO 5812 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2016-09-27 12:47:54.640  INFO 5812 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.11.Final}
2016-09-27 12:47:54.642  INFO 5812 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2016-09-27 12:47:54.644  INFO 5812 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2016-09-27 12:47:54.691  INFO 5812 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2016-09-27 12:47:54.965  INFO 5812 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Started.
2016-09-27 12:47:55.253  INFO 5812 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
2016-09-27 12:47:56.049  INFO 5812 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
2016-09-27 12:47:56.441  INFO 5812 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000230: Schema export complete
2016-09-27 12:47:56.489  INFO 5812 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2016-09-27 12:47:57.575  INFO 5812 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/login],methods=[POST]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.taqnihome.controller.HomeController.login(com.taqnihome.domain.User)
2016-09-27 12:47:57.577  INFO 5812 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/signup],methods=[POST]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.taqnihome.controller.HomeController.saveData(com.taqnihome.domain.User)
2016-09-27 12:47:57.577  INFO 5812 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/search],methods=[POST]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.taqnihome.controller.HomeController.checkMacAddress(com.taqnihome.domain.User)
2016-09-27 12:47:57.577  INFO 5812 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/addGameToProfile],methods=[POST]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.taqnihome.controller.HomeController.addGameToProfile(com.taqnihome.domain.GameProfile)
2016-09-27 12:47:57.578  INFO 5812 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/updateGameToProfile],methods=[PUT]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.taqnihome.controller.HomeController.updateGameToProfile(com.taqnihome.domain.GameProfile)
2016-09-27 12:47:57.578  INFO 5812 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/addGameRequestToLibrary],methods=[POST]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.taqnihome.controller.HomeController.addGameRequestToLibrary(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
2016-09-27 12:47:57.578  INFO 5812 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/getAllLibraryGames],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.taqnihome.controller.HomeController.getAllGames()
2016-09-27 12:47:57.578  INFO 5812 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/getGameProfileByUser],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.taqnihome.controller.HomeController.getAllProfileGames(com.taqnihome.domain.User)
2016-09-27 12:47:57.579  INFO 5812 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/v2/api-docs],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json || application/hal+json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity springfox.documentation.swagger2.web.Swagger2Controller.getDocumentation(java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2016-09-27 12:47:57.584  INFO 5812 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/swagger-resources/configuration/ui]}" onto org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity springfox.documentation.swagger.web.ApiResourceController.uiConfiguration()
2016-09-27 12:47:57.590  INFO 5812 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/swagger-resources/configuration/security]}" onto org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity springfox.documentation.swagger.web.ApiResourceController.securityConfiguration()
2016-09-27 12:47:57.591  INFO 5812 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/swagger-resources]}" onto org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity> springfox.documentation.swagger.web.ApiResourceController.swaggerResources()
2016-09-27 12:47:57.595  INFO 5812 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2016-09-27 12:47:57.595  INFO 5812 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2016-09-27 12:47:57.914  INFO 5812 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@7722c3c3: startup date [Tue Sep 27 12:47:50 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-09-27 12:47:58.017  INFO 5812 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-09-27 12:47:58.017  INFO 5812 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-09-27 12:47:58.068  INFO 5812 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-09-27 12:47:58.430  INFO 5812 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2016-09-27 12:47:58.437  INFO 5812 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'dataSource' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2016-09-27 12:47:58.443  INFO 5812 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located MBean 'dataSource': registering with JMX server as MBean [com.zaxxer.hikari:name=dataSource,type=HikariDataSource]
2016-09-27 12:47:58.449  INFO 5812 --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 2147483647
2016-09-27 12:47:58.449  INFO 5812 --- [           main] d.s.w.p.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper : Context refreshed
2016-09-27 12:47:58.476  INFO 5812 --- [           main] d.s.w.p.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper : Found 1 custom documentation plugin(s)
2016-09-27 12:47:58.487  INFO 5812 --- [           main] s.d.s.w.s.ApiListingReferenceScanner     : Scanning for api listing references
2016-09-27 12:47:58.843  INFO 5812 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2016-09-27 12:47:58.850  INFO 5812 --- [           main] c.t.application.TaqnihomeApplication     : Started TaqnihomeApplication in 8.563 seconds (JVM running for 8.995)
```

Comment: Please don't shout.

Comment: Is your configuration file a reward?

Comment: I read your stack trace, and I raised you an answer.
I'm going to suggest an edit to shrink your stack trace, and point out the specifics.

Comment: Great, the gods have become annoyed with it. Little do they know it's not off topic, and the problem is provided (just needs to be made concise). If the problem no longer persists, hopefully you can mark an answer and remove the last logs. Otherwise, edit the question to explain what problem persists.

Comment: I would suggest moving the logs off to gists (https://gist.github.com/) and linking back to them.

Answer (score 2):

Hibernate is pitching a fit because you told it to do this (intentionally or not):

```
alter table game_library add column game_id varchar(255) not null
```

However, `Table 'testingjpa.game_library' doesn't exist`.

Either fix your DB or fix your `game_library` object definition or mapping.

It's probably gone from your DB, or you're pointing it at a wrong or older DB.

Comment: im using MySql Workbench and the version is 5.7

Comment: You said in a comment on @nbrooks answer that you changed update to create, and it created the tables. Perhaps you should update your question with new log output?

Comment: You could also post the list of tables in the DB (e.g. MySQL: `SHOW TABLES`)

Comment: added new logs when using create in ddl-auto

Comment: According to those logs... everything worked?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the error message that Hibernate is providing you:

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'testingjpa.game_library' doesn't exist

You're referring to a table that doesn't yet exist in your database, or that your DB user does not have access to. This is causing Spring to fail when it's setting up your Entity Manager Factory, and ultimately the entire Spring context. The errant SQL statement seems to be:

> alter table game_library add column game_id varchar(255) not null

If this is in a schema.sql file, or some other schema configuration file that you're running to setup your database, you'll have to ensure that the table is created correctly before you run this `alter` statement.

Have a look at the Spring Boot doc on [Database initialization](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html). If you're expecting the table to be auto-generated, ensure that you have the `spring.jpa.generate-ddl` flag set to true in your application.properties file.

Comment: There is a log statement; `HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update` ... doesn't that imply `generate-ddl` is already `true`?

Comment: @TylerY86 Good point, I'm not sure. I'd have to run an example to see what Hibernate logs.

Comment: @TylerY86 yeah its already true

Comment: @TylerY86 issue with only game_library class. i have other class named game_category and table is created for that but not for game_library. can you want to look into game_library object ?

Comment: I think @nbrooks would be better qualified to help you there. You're welcome to update your post and modify your question to include the game_library definition. :)

Comment: @TylerY86 if im changing spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update to create then its create all the tables for me.

Comment: @nbrooks now you are the hope for me :(

Comment: @ashishraval Please update your question with any relevant details

Comment: @nbrooks added game_library object in snippet

Comment: finally got answered after lot of hard work , its a problem due to newer version of mysql workbench